# Graph theory, isomer enumeration and chemical graph theory

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, reference-request

Where could we find a good description of graph theory applied to the general problem of isomer enumeration and chemical graph theory?

Comment: Isomer enumeration requires group theory, I'd rather say.

Comment: Polya enumeration theory is not a part of group theory as far as I know...